# In firefox, when a select has position and a z-index, why do change events not fire on tab?

Tags: javascript, firefox

Looking for any information on why a change event would fire on a  without position or z-index, and why it wouldn't fire if those styles do exist. This problem occurs in **Firefox** only.

**Change event does not fire on tab**

```
<select style="position: relative; z-index:1"><option>1</option><option>2</option></select>
```

**Change event does not fire on tab**

```
<select><option>1</option><option>2</option>
```

**Change event sample code (using jQuery**

```
$('select').on('change', function(e){ console.log(e.type) });
```

Please see [this CodePen](http://codepen.io/gnettles/pen/MYeBro) for a working example.

Comment: It works for me. When I hit `tab` it prints `blur` on both respectively. Is it possibly your browser? BTW, the code in your post is invalid - you mean `...z-index: 1;"`

Comment: Both work fine and your code isn't valid.

Comment: NOTE: the issue is only observed when using the keyboard to change the select.

Comment: @philtune - I updated that sample code, it being invalid does not effect the outcome, take a look at the Codepen. As the title mentions - the "change" event does not fire in the second case - I am aware the "blur" event does.

Comment: @philtune are you using firefox? The change event does not fire on the second box for me when: focusing the select, pressing down, pressing tab.

Comment: I don't think `z-index` would have to do anything with this issue.

Comment: @A.Wolff the title clearly states firefox =)

Comment: Ahh, yeah, that was my first comment... `Is it possibly your browser?` Yeah, I'm using Chrome. ... So my bad for not reading the specification in the title, but it's worth noting that those specifications should ALSO be put in the body of the question, and optimally, relevant tags should be added.

Comment: If you're anticipating tab usage, why not use the tabindex attribute?

Comment: @philtune copy that - will do in the future.

Comment: @slime select elements naturally can be tabbed to without tabindex, I dont believe that is relevant to the problem

Comment: Hmm, now I'm getting the issue on BOTH select elements in Firefox. Can't get either to work using the up/down arrows. Well crap... I just now realized all my form applications with `select` have the same issue in Firefox. They've been QA'd, so I wonder if this is a bug with a newer version. I'm glad you posted this then!

Comment: @philtune interesting. What version of FF are you using? I still see the behavior on FF34 Mac. Are you pressing tab after using the up/down arrows?

Comment: Both sides are behaving exactly the same for me in Firefox, but when using the keyboard to go between the options, the change is not fired, not until you hit enter on the option you just selected.

Comment: Found this https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=126379... looking for more. I'm using 33.1.1.

Comment: What is the purpose of this CSS rule: `.rel select:focus {...}` I mean why setting it?

Comment: This looks like it's a "won'tfix": https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=110800... they say it's not *supposed* to fire on arrow clicks. (though this is super old, so not sure if it's still relevant)

Comment: @philtune It should when input loses focus

Comment: @philtune I am not expecting it to fire when you press arrow, but when you press tab after pressing arrow - the left example **does** fire a change event on FF34 Mac (for me)

Comment: @A.Wolff Fair question. This is a reduced test case of a problem I'm seeing where a select element has a "focus" state with a large dropshadow. When a select is focused without the z-index, the dropshadow can be clipped by sibling elements in some cases. This is neither here nor there in regards to this bug - but there's the context anyway =)

Comment: OIC, well then I'm back to "it works for me" on FF. Hitting `tab` on either seems to fire the blur. Your event (`e.type`) is "blur" and that's what it's printing.

Comment: @philtune Again we're looking for the change event, not blur. And "e" would be _any_ event that takes place on the select.

Comment: @Greg If i remove `position: relative;` from this CSS rule `.rel select:focus {...}` it works as expected for me on FF

Comment: I think it's a faulty assumption that tabbing = change event. It fires when it's truly changed, not when it loses focus. I'm FF34 on Windows here and it works exactly as it's expected to.

Comment: @A.Wolff yes exactly - the question is why does removing relative cause it to work.

Comment: @slime I hear you - but tabbing does work in the left instance to select (at least for me an some others)

Comment: Doh, i'm must be tired, sorry to make you lose so much time answering useless comment, i should read better question, my bad, again...

Answer (score 0):

It appears this problem can be resolved by setting position before the `select` receives focus, like so:

```
select { position: relative; }
select:focus { z-index: 1; }
```

I would still be curious if anyone has insight into why this happens when changing the position of the `select` on `:focus`